# Use of unresolved identifier 'form' Swift4 (Eureka Form builder)

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

> POD file
>
> platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> target 'ParamLeaveApp' do   use_frameworks!
>
> pod 'Eureka'
>
> pod 'Firebase/Core'
>   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
>
> end

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class UserInfoViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        form +++ Section("Personal Info") .       <--- Here is the error showing "use of unresolved identifier".

            <<< TextRow() { row in
                row.title = "Username"
                row.placeholder = "Username"
            }

            <<< TextRow() { row in
                row.title = "Password"
                row.placeholder = "Password"
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and then rebuilding?

Comment: Also why is there a period at the end of the line that throws the error?

Comment: @Daniel That period is by mistake and I resolved the issue there were 2 FormViewController in my repository so I renamed the other one!